# Facing strange issue while executing Oracle Stored procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

I am facing a weird issue while executing a Oracle stored procedure. I was able to select the data it just that troubling while inserting selected data to another 
table.

Below is the query which is causing problem.

```
BEGIN
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
'INSERT INTO STG_MEMBER_MONTH_1
(
 MEMBER_ID
,EMPLOYER_GROUP_ID
,MEMBER_BIRTH_DATE
,SPAN_FROM_DATE
,GROUP_ID_FINAL
,GROUP_SIZE
,NAME_TO_BE_USED
,MEM_DOB
,MM
,MEMBER_AGE_FINAL
,ELIG_YEAR
,ELIG_MONTH
,AGE_BAND
)
WITH CTE_Member_Month_Group_Id_Final AS (
SELECT
 a.MEMBER_ID
,a.EMPLOYER_GROUP_ID
,a.MEMBER_BIRTH_DATE
,a.SPAN_FROM_DATE
b.ACCOUNT_NUM as GROUP_ID_FINAL
from STG_MEMBER_MONTH_2 a LEFT JOIN
(SELECT DISTINCT GRP_ID,ACCOUNT_NUM from ACCOUNT_MAPPING)b
ON a.EMPLOYER_GROUP_ID= b.GRP_ID)

,CTE_Member_Month_Group_Name as (
    SELECT a.*,b.GROUP_SIZE,b.GROUP_NAME as NAME_TO_BE_USED 
    from CTE_Member_Month_Group_Id_Final  a
    LEFT JOIN APP_CALENDAR b
    ON a.GROUP_ID_FINAL= b.GROUP_ID
)
,CTE_Max_DOB AS (
     SELECT a.MEMBER_ID,b.MEMBER_BIRTH_DATE AS MEM_DOB from
       (SELECT MEMBER_ID,max(SPAN_FROM_DATE) as SPAN_FROM_DATE from CTE_Member_Month_Group_Name
        GROUP BY MEMBER_ID)
     LEFT OUTER JOIN CTE_Member_Month_Group_Name b
     ON a.MEMBER_ID = b.MEMBER_ID
     AND a.SPAN_FROM_DATE = b.SPAN_FROM_DATE)
,CTE_Age_Band_Prev AS (
     SELECT a.*,b.MEM_DOB,1 as "MM"
    ,trunc(months_between(a.SPAN_FROM_DATE,B.MEM_DOB)/12) as "MEMBER_AGE_FINAL"
    ,extract(year from a.SPAN_FROM_DATE)                  as "ELIG_YEAR"
    ,extract(month from a.SPAN_FROM_DATE)                 as "ELIG_MONTH"
    from CTE_Member_Month_Group_Name a
    LEFT OUTER JOIN CTE_Max_DOB  b
    ON a.MEMBER_ID=b.MEMBER_ID
)
,CTE_Age_Band AS (
    SELECT a.*,
    CASE
        WHEN ltrim("MEMBER_AGE_FINAL") < 1 
        THEN 'Less than one year'
        WHEN ltrim("MEMBER_AGE_FINAL") > 17 and ltrim("MEMBER_AGE_FINAL") <=29 
        THEN '18 - 29 years'
        WHEN ltrim("MEMBER_AGE_FINAL") > 29 and ltrim("MEMBER_AGE_FINAL") <=39 
        THEN '29 - 39 years'
        ELSE 'More than 40 years'
    END as "AGE_BAND"
    from CTE_Age_Band_Prev a

)
SELECT * from CTE_Age_Band';
END;
/
```

I am able to select everything from `CTE_Age_Band` without any issues but was not able to insert that selected data to table `STG_MEMBER_MONTH_1`.
I am getting below error message

```
ORA-06550: LINE 57,column 1:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "," when expecting one of the following:
```

If I removed the last CTE `CTE_Age_Band` from above statement and remove the column `AGE_BAND` from insert statement it is getting executed without any errors.
Changed logic is shown below:

```
BEGIN
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
'INSERT INTO STG_MEMBER_MONTH_1
(
 MEMBER_ID
,EMPLOYER_GROUP_ID
,MEMBER_BIRTH_DATE
,SPAN_FROM_DATE
,GROUP_ID_FINAL
,GROUP_SIZE
,NAME_TO_BE_USED
,MEM_DOB
,MM
,MEMBER_AGE_FINAL
,ELIG_YEAR
,ELIG_MONTH
)
WITH CTE_Member_Month_Group_Id_Final AS (
SELECT
 a.MEMBER_ID
,a.EMPLOYER_GROUP_ID
,a.MEMBER_BIRTH_DATE
,a.SPAN_FROM_DATE
b.ACCOUNT_NUM as GROUP_ID_FINAL
from STG_MEMBER_MONTH_2 a LEFT JOIN
(SELECT DISTINCT GRP_ID,ACCOUNT_NUM from ACCOUNT_MAPPING)b
ON a.EMPLOYER_GROUP_ID= b.GRP_ID)

,CTE_Member_Month_Group_Name as (
SELECT a.*,b.GROUP_SIZE,b.GROUP_NAME as NAME_TO_BE_USED from CTE_Member_Month_Group_Id_Final  a
LEFT JOIN APP_CALENDAR b
ON a.GROUP_ID_FINAL= b.GROUP_ID
)
,CTE_Max_DOB AS (
SELECT a.MEMBER_ID,b.MEMBER_BIRTH_DATE AS MEM_DOB from
       (SELECT MEMBER_ID,max(SPAN_FROM_DATE) as SPAN_FROM_DATE from CTE_Member_Month_Group_Name
        GROUP BY MEMBER_ID)
LEFT OUTER JOIN CTE_Member_Month_Group_Name b
ON a.MEMBER_ID = b.MEMBER_ID
AND a.SPAN_FROM_DATE = b.SPAN_FROM_DATE)
,CTE_Age_Band_Prev AS (
   SELECT a.*,b.MEM_DOB,1 as "MM"
   ,trunc(months_between(a.SPAN_FROM_DATE,B.MEM_DOB)/12) as "MEMBER_AGE_FINAL"
   ,extract(year from a.SPAN_FROM_DATE)                  as "ELIG_YEAR"
   ,extract(month from a.SPAN_FROM_DATE)                 as "ELIG_MONTH"
   from CTE_Member_Month_Group_Name a
   LEFT OUTER JOIN CTE_Max_DOB  b
   ON a.MEMBER_ID=b.MEMBER_ID
)
SELECT * from CTE_Age_Band_Prev';
END;
/
```

Looks like there is some silly mistake in the last CTE '`CTE_Age_Band`' which I am not able to figured out.

Comment: You should See the error even by syntax coloring.

Comment: Whats that?. I am very new to oracle. Just doing. Conversion from sql server to oracle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is the string literals inside your SQL string. To have a single-quote put into the string you need to double the single quotes, i.e. put two of them side by side:

```
BEGIN
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
'INSERT INTO STG_MEMBER_MONTH_1
(
 MEMBER_ID
,EMPLOYER_GROUP_ID
,MEMBER_BIRTH_DATE
,SPAN_FROM_DATE
,GROUP_ID_FINAL
,GROUP_SIZE
,NAME_TO_BE_USED
,MEM_DOB
,MM
,MEMBER_AGE_FINAL
,ELIG_YEAR
,ELIG_MONTH
,AGE_BAND
)
WITH CTE_Member_Month_Group_Id_Final AS (
SELECT
 a.MEMBER_ID
,a.EMPLOYER_GROUP_ID
,a.MEMBER_BIRTH_DATE
,a.SPAN_FROM_DATE
b.ACCOUNT_NUM as GROUP_ID_FINAL
from STG_MEMBER_MONTH_2 a LEFT JOIN
(SELECT DISTINCT GRP_ID,ACCOUNT_NUM from ACCOUNT_MAPPING)b
ON a.EMPLOYER_GROUP_ID= b.GRP_ID)

,CTE_Member_Month_Group_Name as (
    SELECT a.*,b.GROUP_SIZE,b.GROUP_NAME as NAME_TO_BE_USED 
    from CTE_Member_Month_Group_Id_Final  a
    LEFT JOIN APP_CALENDAR b
    ON a.GROUP_ID_FINAL= b.GROUP_ID
)
,CTE_Max_DOB AS (
     SELECT a.MEMBER_ID,b.MEMBER_BIRTH_DATE AS MEM_DOB from
       (SELECT MEMBER_ID,max(SPAN_FROM_DATE) as SPAN_FROM_DATE from CTE_Member_Month_Group_Name
        GROUP BY MEMBER_ID)
     LEFT OUTER JOIN CTE_Member_Month_Group_Name b
     ON a.MEMBER_ID = b.MEMBER_ID
     AND a.SPAN_FROM_DATE = b.SPAN_FROM_DATE)
,CTE_Age_Band_Prev AS (
     SELECT a.*,b.MEM_DOB,1 as "MM"
    ,trunc(months_between(a.SPAN_FROM_DATE,B.MEM_DOB)/12) as "MEMBER_AGE_FINAL"
    ,extract(year from a.SPAN_FROM_DATE)                  as "ELIG_YEAR"
    ,extract(month from a.SPAN_FROM_DATE)                 as "ELIG_MONTH"
    from CTE_Member_Month_Group_Name a
    LEFT OUTER JOIN CTE_Max_DOB  b
    ON a.MEMBER_ID=b.MEMBER_ID
)
,CTE_Age_Band AS (
    SELECT a.*,
    CASE
        WHEN ltrim("MEMBER_AGE_FINAL") < 1 
        THEN ''Less than one year''
        WHEN ltrim("MEMBER_AGE_FINAL") > 17 and ltrim("MEMBER_AGE_FINAL") <=29 
        THEN ''18 - 29 years''
        WHEN ltrim("MEMBER_AGE_FINAL") > 29 and ltrim("MEMBER_AGE_FINAL") <=39 
        THEN ''29 - 39 years''
        ELSE ''More than 40 years''
    END as "AGE_BAND"
    from CTE_Age_Band_Prev a

)
SELECT * from CTE_Age_Band';
END;
/
```

Comment: @bob-jarvis-reinstate-monica...you made my day. Thank you so much. Oracle is bit diffrent than sql server specially procedure execution. Thanks

Comment: "A bit different"?  Oracle is a _lot_ different, in a lot more ways than you realize.  They are fundamentally different from the ground up.  "Best practice" in one is quite often "worst practice" in the other due to the very  fundamental ways the rdbms is architected and designed.  The similarities begin and end with SELECT * FROM MYTABLE;

Comment: I **do** wonder why you're using `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` here, as I see no reason why you'd need it here. ?????

Comment: @Bob Jarvis - Reinstate Monica.. i am creating stg_member_month_2 on the fly with in same procedure. I have used this table in the first cte.

Comment: @edstevens.. I do agree with you. I faced a lot difficulties while doing conversion.. and i mistakenly given the wrong estimate to my client as well. Conversion took much more time then what i anticipated.

Comment: Perhaps `STG_MEMBER_MONTH_2` should be a global temp table or something of that sort. At the very least build it once and TRUNCATE it at runtime, but don't go through the agony of having to recreate indexes, access permissions, etc on the fly - which is also a security hole large enough to sail the Queen Mary through. Just a thought...

Comment: Thanks. I will definetly look into this. Thanks to you and others for kind support and help